# Call method of unknown object

Tags: java, class, object, nosuchmethoderror

I have two ArrayLists - ArrayList1 and ArrayList2. Each of them is filled with objects - Object1 and Object2, respectively.
Both of these objects have method 'getText'.

Object1:

```
public String getText() { return "1";}
```

Object2:

```
public String getText() { return "2";}
```

At certain point I would like to loop through each of these lists using the same method (just with different parameter).

```
loopThroughList(1)
loopThroughList(2)
```

What is the syntax if I want to call a method, but I don't know which object it is going to be? This is the code I have so far:

```
for (Object o : lists.getList(listNumber)) {
    System.out.println(o.getText());
}
```

It says *Cannot resolve method getText*. I googled around and found another solution:

```
for (Object o : lists.getList(listNumber)) {
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getMethod("getText"));
}
```

But this gives me *NoSuchMethodException* error. Even though the 'getText' method is public.

**EDIT:** To get the correct list, I am calling the method 'getList' of a different object (lists) that returns either ArrayList1 or ArrayList2 (depending on the provided parameter).

```
class Lists

public getList(list) {
    if (list == 1) {
        return ArrayList1;
    }
    else if (list == 2) {
        return ArrayList2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an interface that declares the `getText()` method, have both your objects implement it, then declare your list as a `List<NameOfTheInterface>` . That way you can do `for (NameOfTheInterface o : lists.getList(listNumber))` and call `o.getText()`  .

Comment: How is declared `lists` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an interface for the `getText` method

```
public interface YourInterface {

    String getText();     

}
```

Implement the interface on the respective classes

```
public class Object1 implements YourInterface {

    @Override
    public String getText() { 
        return "1";
    }

}

public class Object2 implements YourInterface {

    @Override
    public String getText() { 
        return "2";
    }

}
```

Modify your `getList` method to return `List<YourInterface>`

```
public static List<YourInterface> getList(int list){
    List<YourInterface> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(list == 1){
        // your initial type
         List<Object1> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
         result.addAll(firstList);
    } else {
        // your initial type
        List<Object2> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
        result.addAll(secondList);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Declaration for `loopThroughList`

```
public static void loopThroughList(List<YourInterface> list){
    list.forEach(yourInterface -> System.out.println(yourInterface.getText()));
}
```

Sample usage.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    loopThroughList(getList(1));
    loopThroughList(getList(2));
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the declaration of loopThroughList, taking into account the edit of the original question?

Comment: `loopThroughList` should accept objects of type `ArrayList<Object1>` or `ArrayList<Object2>`, considering both `Object1` and `Object2` implement `YourInterface`.

Comment: Could you provide the implementation for `getList` in your question?

Comment: I suppose you have `ArrayList<Object1>` and `ArrayList<Object2>`, not two different types of `ArrayList`, right?

Comment: @JanHorčička Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

This is where `interface`s come in.

```
interface HasText {
    public String getText();
}

class Object1 implements HasText {
    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return "1";
    }
}

class Object2 implements HasText {
    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return "2";
    }
}

private void test() {
    List<HasText> list = Arrays.asList(new Object1(), new Object2());
    for (HasText ht : list) {
        System.out.println(ht);
    }
}
```

If one of your objects is not in your control you can use a Wrapper class.

```
class Object3DoesNotImplementHasText {
    public String getText() {
        return "3";
    }
}

class Object3Wrapper implements HasText{
    final Object3DoesNotImplementHasText it;

    public Object3Wrapper(Object3DoesNotImplementHasText it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return it.getText();
    }
}

private void test() {
    List<HasText> list = Arrays.asList(new Object1(), new Object2(), new Object3Wrapper(new Object3DoesNotImplementHasText()));
    for (HasText ht : list) {
        System.out.println(ht);
    }
}
```

Comment: In which class file do I define the interface?

Comment: @JanHorčička - Anywhere really ... it depends where you want to use them.

Comment: in a seperate one, create a new HasText.java file with public interface inside.

Comment: I used your solution, but it doesn't work. I created an interface and made the two classes implement it (as it is in your code). The error message is still the same. Maybe the reason is that I am getting the correct list from another object (see edit in the original post).

Comment: @JanHorčička I have added the wrapper trick to wrap objects that do not implement your interface.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really don't understand the first line in the test() method. Can we just get the list by calling the "getList" method instead of creating new Objects?

Comment: @JanHorčička - That's just me creating test data so I don't need to enter it manually. Use whatever technique you like.

Answer (score 2):

This is awful. Can you elaborate on what specifically you are trying to do? Java is strong typed by design, and you are trying to get around it. Why? Instead of Object, use the specific class, or interface as previously suggested. If that's not possible, and you must use lists of Objects, use instanceof and casting eg:

```
for (Object o : lists.getList(listNumber)) {
    if (o instanceof Object1) {
        Object1 o1 = (Object1) o;
        System.out.println(o1.getText());
    } else if (o instanceof Object2) {
        Object2 o2 = (Object2) o;
        System.out.println(o2.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces work great here, but there a couple of other options if you're dealing with legacy code and cannot use interfaces.

First would be to cast the list items into their respective types:

```
for (Object o : lists.getList(listNumber)) {
    if(o instanceof Object1) {
        Object1 o1 = (Object1)o;
        System.out.println(o1.getText());
    }
    else if(o instanceof Object2) {
        Object1 o2 = (Object2)o;
        System.out.println(o2.getText());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Unknown class");
    }
}
```

You can also use reflection to see if the object has a `getText` method and then invoke it:

```
for (Object o : lists.getList(listNumber)) {
    try {
        System.out.println(o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getName").invoke(o));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Object doesn't have getText method");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add more to this answer and give you some more to think on this (Will try to do it in a simple, non-formal way). Using interfaces is the proper way of doing such operation. However, I want to stand on the "bad idea":

```
for (Object o : lists.getList(listNumber)) {
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getMethod("getText"));
}
```

What you are doing here, is using a mechanism called [Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html):

> Reflection is a feature in the Java programming language. It allows an
>   executing Java program to examine or "introspect" upon itself, and
>   manipulate internal properties of the program. For example, it's
>   possible for a Java class to obtain the names of all its members and
>   display them.

What you actually attempted, is using that mechanism, to retrieve the method through a `Class` reflection object instance of your Class (sounds weird, isn't it?).

From that perspective, you need to think that, if you want to invoke your method, you now have, in a sense, a meta-Class instance to manipulate your objects. Think of it like an Object that is one step above your Objects (Similarly to a dream inside a dream, in *Inception*). In that sense, you need to retrieve the method, and then invoke it in a different (meta-like) way:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method m = o.getClass().getMethod("getText");
m.invoke(o);
```

Using that logic, you could possibly iterate through the object list, check if method exists, then invoke your method.

This is though a bad, **BAD** idea.

Why? Well, the answer relies on reflection itself: reflection is directly associated with **runtime** - i.e. when the program executes, practically doing *all things* at runtime, bypassing the compilation world.

In other words, by doing this, you are bypassing the compilation error mechanism of Java, allowing such errors happen in **runtime**. This can lead to unstable behavior of the program while executing - apart from the performance overhead using Reflection, which will not analyze here.

Side note: While using reflection will require the usage of Checked Exception handling, it still is not a good idea of doing this - as you practically try to duck tape a bad solution.

On the other hand, you can follow the Inheritance mechanism of Java through Classes and Interfaces - define an interface with your method (let's call it `Textable`), make sure that your classes implement it, and then use it as your base object in your list declaration (@alexrolea has implemented this in his answer, as also @OldCurmudgeon has).

This way, your program will still make the method call decision making at Runtime (via a mechanism called *late binding*), but you will not bypass the compilation error mechanism of Java. Think about it: what would happen if you define a Textable implementation without providing the class - a compile error! And what if you set a non-Textable object into the list of `Textable`s? Guess what! A compile error again. And the list goes on....

In general, avoid using Reflection when you are able to do so. Reflection is useful in some cases that you need to handle your program in such a meta-way and there is no other way of making such things. This is not the case though.

UPDATE: As suggested by some answers, you can use `instanceof` to check if you have a specific Class object instance that contains your method, then invoke respectively. While this seems a simple solution, it is bad in terms of scaling: what if you have 1000 *different* classes that implement the *same* method you want to call?

Comment: What if these classes are from a library I can't modify and they don't have a mutual interface in this library? Instance checking + reflection seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

your objects have to implement a common interface.

```
interface GetTextable {
    String getText();
}

class One implements GetTextable {
    private final String text;

    public One(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}

class Two implements GetTextable {
    private final String text;

    public Two(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}

@Test
public void shouldIterate() throws Exception {
    List<GetTextable> toIterate = Arrays.asList(new One("oneText"), new Two("twoText"));
    for(GetTextable obj: toIterate) {
        System.out.println(obj.getText());
    }
}
```